# how to remove everything before the first match of a given word in regex?

Tags: r, regex

A string:

> hey, validation 2345 have values with validity till 9th Jan
>   validation none

In the above string, I want to remove everything before the first validation is found so that my answer should be:

> 2345 have values with validity till 9th Jan validation none

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi Pushpesh , I need to remove everything till the first "validation" word occur, also please note that this "validation" can occur anywhere in the string, but i need to remove everything till the first time the regex captures "validation"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a lazy match with `gsub` function:

```
a <- " hey , validation 2345 have values with validity till 9th Jan validation none"

gsub('^.+?validation(.*)', "\\1",a)
# [1] " 2345 have values with validity till 9th Jan validation none"
```

Comment: thanks , this works :)

Comment: @Ankit if it worked, please accept as answer.